# Sketchup: Ruby array return matching and non matching sub arrays with specific element

Tags: arrays, ruby, sketchup

I have 2 arrays that look like this and I'd like to find the matching and non matching Point3d values.

```rb
a = [['xxx', [0.203125, 0.203125, 0.0], 
      Point3d(12, 1.25984, -0.275591), nil], 
     ['eee', [0.203125, 0.203125, 0.0], 
      Point3d(12, 20.0995, -0.275591), nil]]

b = [['aaa', [0.203125, 0.203125, 0.0], 
      Point3d(10, 1.25984, -0.275591), nil], 
     ['sss', [0.203125, 0.203125, 0.0], 
      Point3d(10, 20.0995, -0.275591), nil], 
     ['www', [0.203125, 0.203125, 0.0], 
      Point3d(12, 1.25984, -0.275591), nil], 
     ['nnn', [0.203125, 0.203125, 0.0], 
      Point3d(12, 20.0995, -0.275591), nil]]
```

should return 2 arrays, one with matching Point3ds...

```rb
result_match = [['xxx', [0.203125, 0.203125, 0.0], 
                 Point3d(12, 1.25984, -0.275591), nil], 
                ['eee', [0.203125, 0.203125, 0.0], 
                 Point3d(12, 20.0995, -0.275591), nil]]
```

and non matching Point3ds...

```rb
result_non_match = [['aaa', [0.203125, 0.203125, 0.0], 
                     Point3d(10, 1.25984, -0.275591), nil], 
                    ['sss', [0.203125, 0.203125, 0.0], 
                     Point3d(10, 20.0995, -0.275591), nil]]
```

I've searched and tried the results that show up but they don't seem to work since they all work with arrays and not point3ds. The closest I found is this but I can't get that to work...

```
samepoint = a.map(&:to_a) & b.map(&:to_a)
```

Comment: Please clarify on what "matching" means in this case and _why_ you expect the results you expect.

Comment: @chris basically the results are based on weather the Point3ds in the subarrays match or not. IE... `Point3d(12, 1.25984, -0.275591)` is in both arrays a[0][3], a[1][3], b[0][3], b[1][3]. And b[2][3], b[3][3] is not in both arrays. Hopefully that helps.

Comment: `a` and `b` already are arrays of arrays. Hence `a.map(&:to_a) ` is just a copy of `a`, and you are basically caluclating `samepoint  = a & b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to create sets of points.

```
a_set = a.map { |x| x[2] }.to_set
b_set = b.map { |x| x[2] }.to_set
```

Now you can find points which occur in both sets using a set intersection `&`, and the difference using `^`.

```
intersect = a_set & b_set
diff = a_set ^ b_set
```

Having gotten these values, need only filter your arrays to match for those values.

```
matches = (a + b).select { |x| intersect.include?(x[2]) }
```

Comment: I had to make the following changes, let me know if they make sense... had to change `x[2]` to `x[2].to_a`  and to get the matches I had to change `(a + b)` to `(a - b)`